# How do I remove the X from the likert categories in HH?

Tags: r, plot, graph, likert

I have some likert data, where the scales are from 1 to 5. When I read the CSV file, R puts an X in front of the numbers, which is fine.

When I do likert(df), the graph generated has the categories with the X and I can't figure out a way to remove them.
[image]

Comment: Consider changing the column names of your df before plotting and remove the X in this step, e.g., like `colnames(df) <- gsub("X", "count", colnames(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was:

```
"name"<-`colnames<-`("data for the likert scale",c("Question", "NA", "None", "Few (1-25%)", "Some (26-50%)", "Most (51-75%)", "Almost all (76-99%)", "All (100%)"))
```

So the function `colnames<`is the key. You just put in your dataframe as the object, followed by a comma and a vector (starting with "c(...)") to name the columns accordingly.

This basically means that you rename the columns (if you have a dataframe where rows are questions and columns are likert-formatted answers) from the weird X-formatting to e.g. "Question" (col 0), "NA" (col 1), "None" (col 2) etc! Turned out fine for me:

[image: Example of what it looks like in final form]